# AJAX AutoComplete in C# asp.net 4.5 Not Working

Tags: c#, asp.net, autocomplete, ajaxcontroltoolkit, .net-4.5

I am trying to use AJAX for the first time and I am getting nowhere. I have read numerous websites and as far as I can tell my code is correct but when I test the page I am not getting any results.

Here is my aspx code:

```cs
<%@ Page Title="Search" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Search.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Search.aspx.cs" Inherits="NEReval.Search" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajax" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server" EnableViewState="True">

    <ajax:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="True">  
    </ajax:ToolkitScriptManager> 

    <asp:TextBox ID="tbxSearch" runat="server" TabIndex="9" Style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 35px" Height="21px" Width="400px"></asp:TextBox>
    <ajax:AutoCompleteExtender   
        ID="AutoCompleteExtender1"   
        TargetControlID="tbxSearch"
        MinimumPrefixLength="1"   
        CompletionSetCount="10"
        ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList"
        ServicePath="AutoCompleteService.asmx"
        runat="server" />
```

And here is my code behind which is in a file called AutoCompleteService.asmx

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace NEReval
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for AutoCompleteService
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://www.nereval.com/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class AutoCompleteService : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [System.Web.Services.WebMethodAttribute(), System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethodAttribute()]
        public static string[] GetCompletionList(string prefixText, int count)
        {
            List<String> Return = SearchList.GetSearchList(HttpContext.Current.Session["sTown"].ToString());

            return (from r in Return where r.StartsWith(prefixText, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) select r).Take(count).ToArray();
        } 
    }
}
```

I have tested and GetSearchList is never called so it is not calling GetCompletionList. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong? I am programming this in Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web.

Comment: Is your `.asmx` web service actually at the same level as your master page or is the path wrong?

Comment: Have you looked at the IIs logs to see if you are requesting the web service at a different URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove this is a web service issue, in your search page code-behind create a page method, like this:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string[] GetCompletionList()
{
    List<String> Return = SearchList.GetSearchList(HttpContext.Current.Session["sTown"].ToString());

    return (from r in Return where r.StartsWith(prefixText, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) select r).Take(count).ToArray();
}
```

Note: ASP.NET Page Methods must be `static`. Also you will probably need to add a few `using`s to get the code to compile.

Now you can call this page method in your autocompleteextender markup as just the method name, because it is local to your markup, like this:

```
ServicePath="GetCompletionList"
```

Comment: This works, I will just use it here, any reason why it would work here and not in the asmx file just for future knowledge? They are both at the same path.

Comment: Looking at the web service code no, but web services can be tricky and very hard to diagnose without actually running the code. Wish I had a better answer for you, sorry.

Comment: OK, at least I know it wasn't a code problem I was making. Thanks for the help.